# Support Level Pricing Best Practices

Tags: bestpractice

What are best practices around handling Support Level Pricing adders where the adders are not fixed dollar values, but percentages on top of a subscription model (+10%, +25%, etc)?

Is this best handled with different Pricebooks per Support Level?  ... or best handled by adding $0 PricebookEntries for the different levels and calculate a % adder based on it's inclusion in the OpportunityLineItem table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have something similar in our environment.

- Subscription license unit price = 100.00, qty = 5, total price = 500
- Support (Silver) support price = 20% net license price = .20 * 500 = 100
- Total quote = 500+100 = 600

  and here is what I did:

  1. Each support SKU has a `Product2` - e.g. Bronze-SKU, Silver-SKU, Gold-SKU; of course, there are also subscription license SKUs as well.
  2. The `Product2` record has a custom field `Support_as_Pct_of_License__c`, type Percent. Values would be 10, 20, 30, etc based on support SKU and set up in advance.
  3. Each support SKU has a `pricebookentry` on all pricebooks where their related license SKU appears. The `pricebookentry` price is 0.00
  4. There is a custom quoting application that calculates the support price as a % of net license price (that is, after discounts on the license SKU; overrides to the custom `Product2.Support_as_Pct_of_License__c` field are permitted (say, you need to offer 19% instead of 20% for Silver)

Obviously, your quoting app will be different and what I did may not work in your use case